# How do I access PDF form fields with python

Tags: python, pdf

I need to automatically save pdf form fields to a database and write some of them later to new forms I am sending out. I can save the fields no problem but I don't know how to write to a PDF form field .. I am using pdf miner but I can't find anything in it to do this. 
Can any one point me in the direction of a solution?

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43680515/1303068 answer

Answer (score 1):

Reports labs has a open source PDF kit that let you write PDFs, including form fields http://www.reportlab.com. They also have commercial product the reads PDFs. But I've only used the open source version.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but people seem to like [PyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)

Comment: Both PyPdf and ReportLab are good.  I'm traveling at the moment, and don't have the opportunity to answer this question fully.  I want to make a couple of points for now, though:  Philip, if you're still looking for help beyond the references already supplied, say so, and we'll provide more details.  Also, I want readers to know that we've recently begun advancing [a fork of PyPdf](https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2), with Mathieu's blessing.  While it has a long way to go, it already includes several enhancements.  I'll have more to announce soon.

Comment: That first sentence was supposed to be, "Both PyPdf and ReportLab are valuable; both have limits"; apparently I messed up the edit.