# pdfminer doesn't extract data from filled-out pdf form

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, web-scraping, pdfminer

I'm trying to use [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) to extract the filled-out contents in a pdf form. The instructions for accessing the pdf are:

1. Go to https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/nicweb/InstitutionProfile.aspx?parID_Rssd=1073757&parDT_END=99991231
2. Click "Create Report" next to the **fourth report from the top** (i.e.,Banking Organization Systemic Risk Report (FR Y-15))
3. Click "Your request for a financial report is ready"

To extract the contents in blue, I copied code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984003/how-to-extract-pdf-fields-from-a-filled-out-form-in-python):

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

filename = 'FRY15_1073757_20160630.PDF'
fp = open(filename, 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']

for i in fields:
    field = resolve1(i)
    name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
    print '{0}: {1}'.format(name, value)
```

This didn't extract the data fields as expected -- nothing was printed. I tried the same code on another pdf and it worked so I suspect the failure might have to do with the security setting of the first pdf, which is shown below
[image]

For the second pdf on which the code worked, the security setting shows "Allowed" for all the actions. I also tried using pdfminer's pdf2txt.py functionality (see [here](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/#pdf2txt)) but the filled-out data in the fields in the original pdf form (which is what I want) was not in the converted text file; only the "flat" non-fillable part of the pdf was converted. Interestingly, if I use Adobe Reader's *Save As Text* to convert the pdf to a text file, the fillable part *was* in the converted text file. This is what I've been doing to get around the failed code.

Any idea how I can extract data directly from the pdf form? Thanks.

Comment: Concerning the PDF at https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/NICDataCache/FRY15/FRY15_1073757_20160630.PDF: *The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.* Considering the URL saying "...DataCache..." this is not really surprising...

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the headsup. Link has been revised.

Answer (score 0):

*I can only explain what the problem is but cannot present a solution because I have no working Python knowledge.*

Your code iterates over the immediate children of the **AcroForm** **Fields** array and expect them to represent the form fields.

While this expectation often is fulfilled, it actually only represents a special case: Form fields are arranged as a *tree* structure with that **Fields** array as root element, e.g. in case of your sample document there is large tree:

[image: Fields tree]

Thus, you have to descend into the structure, not merely iterate over the immediate children of **Fields**, to find all form fields.

Comment: Which software did you use to dissect the pdf as shown above? Thanks.

Comment: @Nero I use [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/de/node/7) but any other pdf inspection software should show something like that, too.

Comment: I managed to extract the info I needed by opening the pdf in a text editor but ran into a different problem which I believe is also tied to the internal workings pdf's. Could you please take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232492/pdf-contents-dont-show-up-in-text-editor? Thanks.