# pdfminer error message: pdfminer.pdfdocument.PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed: Text extraction is not allowed

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I need to process some PDF files and add their form field contents in a database.

This document has not Security Method set, as I can see in the PDF Viewer document properties.

I tried the suggestions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984003/how-to-extract-pdf-fields-from-a-filled-out-form-in-python/3985696#3985696).

When I test using pdfminer (or pdfminer.six), I didn't get an error message, but it didn't retrieve any field.

Using PyPDF2, I get the error message: "file has not been decrypted."

This is the pdfminer code:

```
import sys
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

fname=r'D:\Atrium\Projects\CTFC\psgf\database\19022021\formulari-dinamic-redaccio-plans-simples-gestio-forestal_Filled.pdf'
fp = open(fname, 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
for i in fields:
    field = resolve1(i)
    name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(name, value))
print('Done!')
```

A sample file can be download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YcxqdxgWyVVSpGcWCI6UuAEkdpr8xbDs/view?usp=sharing).

How can I do to obtain field names and content?

Comment: Your example file contains a XFA form, i.e. not the normal **AcroForm** form definition you look for. PDF with XFA forms are a deprecated technology.

Comment: Tks! However, the PDF forms are already filled, how can I proceed to access data fields, or you know if there's any tool to convert XFA in Acroform?

Comment: Well, essentially the xfa form definition is an xml file embedded either as a whole or separated in parts. You can extract it and read data from the xml. It's located in the **AcroForm** dictionary as value of the key **XFA**.

Answer (score 1):

As mkl explained, my PDF files store form data in XFA form, a deprecated format. The XFA is an array of XML docs and I have to procure field names in each one of these docs.

I used PyPDF2 library to do that:

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fname=r'form.pdf'

def findInDict(needle, haystack):
    xlas = []
    for key in haystack.keys():
        try:
            value=haystack[key]
        except:
            continue
        if key==needle:
            return value
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            x=findInDict(needle,value)
            if x is not None:
                return x

pdfobject=open(fname,'rb')
pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
xfaparts=findInDict('/XFA',pdf.resolvedObjects)

for xfa in xfaparts:
    if isinstance(xfa,pypdf.generic.IndirectObject):
        xml = str(xfa.getObject().getData())
        ## Then process XML to find form tags
```