# Getting none from fields while parsing a pdf file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to parse a pdf file. I want to get all the values in a list or dictionary of the checkbox values. But I am getting this error.

> "return OrderedDict((k, v.get('/V', '')) for k, v in fields.items())
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'"

The code I am trying is this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def _getFields(obj, tree=None, retval=None, fileobj=None):
    
    fieldAttributes = {'/FT': 'Field Type', '/Parent': 'Parent', '/T': 'Field Name', '/TU': 'Alternate Field Name',
                       '/TM': 'Mapping Name', '/Ff': 'Field Flags', '/V': 'Value', '/DV': 'Default Value'}
    if retval is None:
        retval = OrderedDict()
        catalog = obj.trailer["/Root"]
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" in catalog:
            tree = catalog["/AcroForm"]
        else:
            return None
    if tree is None:
        return retval

    obj._checkKids(tree, retval, fileobj)
    for attr in fieldAttributes:
        if attr in tree:
            # Tree is a field
            obj._buildField(tree, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)
            break

    if "/Fields" in tree:
        fields = tree["/Fields"]
        for f in fields:
            field = f.getObject()
            obj._buildField(field, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)

    return retval

def get_form_fields(infile):
    infile = PdfFileReader(open(infile, 'rb'))
    fields = _getFields(infile)
    return OrderedDict((k, v.get('/V', '')) for k, v in fields.items())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint

    pdf_file_name = 'Guild.pdf'

    pprint(get_form_fields(pdf_file_name))
```

Comment: `retval` is None, and the document does not contain an `AcroForm`, so your `_getFields` function returns `None`.  There are no fields.  Perhaps you need to add `if not fields: return None`.

Comment: Why did you write `return None` in `_getFields`? Or why did you think that `None` has an attribute `items`? I'm a bit confused what exactly your question is.

Comment: I want to get all the values of the checkboxes that are in the pdf file. @mkrieger1

Comment: so what should I change that will get all the values of the checkboxes correctly? can you help? @TimRoberts

Comment: That's just not how PDF files work.  Those checkboxes do not HAVE values.  They're just individual characters within the file.  You're going to have to use the PyPDF2 APIs to extract the text from that document, and see if it gives you the box characters.

Comment: how to do it then? that is my question. can you help? @TimRoberts

Comment: It's not going to be easy.  I can use `pdfminer` to extract all of the text, but it doesn't get the checkboxes.  You may have to look at the individual objects in the PDF file, and I'm not sure PyPDF2 goes to that level of detail.

Comment: that is the problem. I need the values of the checkboxes. @TimRoberts

Comment: No, you can't say that.  The checkboxes don't have values.  Looking at the internals, the checkboxes are just images, so you can't even tell which image is "checked" and which is "unchecked" without a human eye.  You have a lot of work ahead of you.  If the forms are all the same, it MIGHT be easier to convert the PDFs to PNGs, and use an image library to look at the known locations of the checkboxes.

Comment: the code you show is copy-pasted from another [qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984003/how-to-extract-pdf-fields-from-a-filled-out-form-in-python). I checked the pdf-link you provided, but you checked the box or got the pdf already checked?

Comment: the pdf is already checked. I just need to get the values of the checkboxes as a list or dictionary. @cards

Comment: ok. so ocr need to be used for this? @TimRoberts

Comment: the code that you are using works when the fields are "actives". In that case it seems more that were just symbols of a box with a cross

Comment: try to make a new pdf containing some fields and run that code...

Comment: so what should I do to extract the checkboxes values of the pdf I provided? do you have any suggestions? @cards

Comment: ocr... and a new question!

Comment: OCR is one way to do it.  I suspect it will be the easiest way.

Comment: the problem is the pdf files cannot change. It is system generated and look exactly like this @cards

Comment: the problem is that code is useless in this case. forget about pdfminer, pypdf, ... use an ocr approach

Comment: ok. will think of the ocr way then. thanks. @cards

Comment: thanks for the answers. will try the ocr way then. @TimRoberts

Comment: @KJ --  There are two 18x19 images in there.  I assume one is filled, one is unfilled.  The 150x158 image is probably the logo.

Answer (score 0):

After tracing through your code, on the 10th line it seems that `catalog` stores the value `{'/Metadata': IndirectObject(16, 0), '/Pages': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/Type': '/Catalog'}`, meaning `/AcroForm` is not a key in the dictionary and your function returns `None`.

Comment: So what should I write instead of AcroForm? Any suggestions?

Comment: @saxope PyPDF2 seems to be [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file).

Comment: so what should I use to parse the values of the checkboxes of the pdf file? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I visited it actually. The answers seems to talk about text extraction. I need to extract the values of the checkboxes. Can you provide a link which contains that information? I did not find it there

Answer (score -1):

Your `_getFields` explicitly returns `None` from first `if` block.
So basically that's where you could get this error from.